# I am getting "Segmentation Fault" without using pointers. What is happening?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

**RESOLVED**: The segfault was caused by infinite (well, not *actually* infinite) recursion. The infinite recursion took place in my `uint pow(uint a, uint b)` function and its helper function when I forgot to account for the case `b = 0`. When `b = 0`, `b` will decrease, wrapping it around to the `unsigned int` limit, and then keep adding stacks until `b` gets back to 1.

Thank you @chris for helping with debugging, and @vsoftco for suggesting infinite recursion.

---

I'm pretty new to C++. I'm writing a program that has 4 functions and 3 of them are recursive (I suspect the recursive functions pertain to this issue).

Essentially, I know that I run into a segfault when I get to the following line of code:

```
    uint right = (n % pow(10, i)) / pow(10, i - 1);
```

This code is inside the for loop of my `bool isPalindrome(uint)` function. This the only information I have pertaining to the segfault.

I have tried looking for segfault examples on stackoverflow and google, but I can't find any that *don't* pertain to pointers and stuff like that.

What is going wrong here? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Also, please explain any suggestions you make as I am fairly new to C++ and intend to learn as much as I can. The entire source code follows, which I assume is invaluable to this problem.

```
/*
 * AUTHORS:        Thomas D. Fischer (a.k.a. gragas)
 * CREATION DATE:  ----:--:--        (YY:MM:DD)
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint;

bool isPalindrome(uint);
uint length(uint, uint count = 0);
uint pow(uint, uint);
uint powhelper(uint, uint, uint);

int main()
{
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    cout << "Running program..." << endl;

    cout << isPalindrome(12) << endl;

    cout << "Execution Time: " << double(clock() - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

bool isPalindrome(uint n)
{
    for(uint i = 1; i <= length(n)/2; i++)
    {
        uint left  = (n / pow(10, length(n) - i)) % 10;
        uint right = (n % pow(10, i)) / pow(10, i - 1);
        if( left != right )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

uint length(uint n, uint count)
{
    if(n != 0)
        return length(n /= 10, ++count);
    else
        return count;
}

uint pow(uint a, uint b)
{
    if(b != 1)
        return powhelper(a*a, --b, a);
    else
        return a;
}

uint powhelper(uint a, uint b, uint multiplier)
{
    if(b != 1)
        return powhelper(a*multiplier, --b, multiplier);
    else
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the segfault? What values do the relevant variables have? Use a debugger.

Comment: You probably have an infinite recursion somewhere (and therefore the stack is effectively overflowing), use a debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: @chris I have discovered the specific line that gives me the segfault. The post has been updated.

Comment: @chris and @vsoftco , I have found the problem. @vsoftco you are correct, I did not account for my `uint pow(uint a, uint b)` function taking 0 for the second argument, b. This results in infinite recursion because the recursion stops when b hits 1, but with b starting at 0 and only decreasing, it will never hit 1. Thanks to the both of you for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: The recursion is not actually infinite, just insanely large.

Comment: @ooga I thought of that as well, but didn't bother to convolute my comment even further. Nice catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pow() function does not handle the case where b=0. This occurs on the first iteration of the loop (I found by inserting a couple of debug printouts).

In that case --b overflows and becomes a very large number, which causes recursion to overflow the stack.

The segfault comes from the program's stack overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pow` function doesn't properly handle an exponent of `0`, which you pass in on the line in question during the loop's first iteration. Have you considered using `std::pow`?

To elaborate further, you decrement the exponent from zero when calling into `powhelper`. This is well defined to be modulo arithmetic so you'll wind up with a very large number, almost certainly causing stack overflow.

Comment: `std::pow` is a floating point function and may come with all the issues related to converting floating to integral - it might not be a good solution here

Comment: @Matt McNabb Can you elaborate further on how `double` can't exactly represent all 32-bit integers (assuming that `unsigned` is 32 bits here)?

Comment: can you prove that it can?